# How to "rollback" after doing `+` = `-`?

Tags: r, function

**Main Question**

I did

```
> `+` = `-`
> 5 + 2
[1] 3
```

How can I "rollback" without restarting the console? Doing

```
> `+` = sum
```

of course, restores one function of `+` but not all. For example

```
> c(3,4) + c(1,2)
[1] 10
```

How could I restore other functions of `+`?

**Extra related questions**

Is there a name for this "kind of assignment" or the kind of functions that "+" and "-" represent?

What terms can be used to differentiate the function "+" from the function "%+%" that one could create doing

```
`%+%` = function(x,y){print(paste(x,"+",y,"=",x+y))}
```

Comment: what a curious question. seems obvious that you should just remove follow @Gregor's advice and ``rm(`+`)`` -- perhaps you could clarify about what your objective is? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I am only trying to improve my understanding of `R`. There is no application hidden behind this question. I did not know `rm('+')`, nor could I have predicted that it would restore the base function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rm()` removes an object from your workspace.

```
rm(`+`)
```

will remove your custom definition that masks the built-in function.

There is nothing special about the assignment you did. As nrussell points out, infix operators (aka binary operators) are generally possible to define by wrapping them in percent signs. The basic math ones (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`, even `=` and `<-` and logical operators, `==`, `|`, `||`, `&`, `&&`, `<`, etc.) are special in that the parser knows they're binary operators even without being wrapped in `%`. You can see `?Arithmetic` (alias `?"+"`) and `?base::Ops` for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot +1. Are `=` and `<-` considered as math (binary) operators too?

Comment: They both take two arguments, one on the left side, one on the right. And you can call them in "standard" form, e.g., `"<-(x, 1)"`. Whether or not you consider them "math" operators, they are certainly binary/infix operators in the same way as `+` or `*`.

Comment: `[` also has special syntax, and can be called as a normal function as well. I don't include it on this list because it's not a binary/infix operator because it can and regularly dies take more arguments, `"["(mtcars, 4:5, 1:3)`. It's special syntax isn't of the form `object operator object`. Another special is `!`, which is unary, not binary (it takes only one argument), but also has special syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can override this by fully qualifying the function in reassignment:

```
`+` = `-`
5 + 2
#[1] 3

`+` <- base::`+`
5 + 2
#[1] 7
```

It's probably better to just `rm` the new function though, as Gregor suggests, otherwise you will just have extra object floating around your environment needlessly.

---

Functions such as `+`, `-`, `*`, etc., and even `%+%` are called infix operators. The difference is that the former are built into the R language (they are primitives), and therefore do not need to be wrapped in `% %` to avoid generating a parsing error.